# How to make org-mode display results in real time?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Whenever I run a source block in emacs org mode, the whole block executes and then I see the results. Is there a way to see the output of the program in real time?

For instance, when installing packages with pip install, the progress bars appear all at once, and they appear one after another (so org mode is not interpreting carriage returns correctly). Is there a header argument or some variable I can set to fix this? If not, where could I insert a filter function to achieve the same result?

Comment: emacs-jupyter does it when it is used with org-babel (e.g., for jupyter-python code blocks). So there is a way to do it that could be applied to other code block types too.  https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter#org-mode-source-blocks